# Why can't I step into this line?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Math.Sign(int.MaxValue);
```

I hit F11 to step into it and it steps right over it. I have all the options set for debugging .NET framework source (I think).

Edit: for someone with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and .NET 3.5 SP1 who can step into this line successfully: what is the size of your .pdb file?

Edit 2: because I can successfully step into System.Windows.Forms, I'm fairly certain I have a corrupted symbol cache, but every time I try to reload the symbols, it re-downloads as only 763KiB.

Edit 3: Is it possible that it I can't step into System.Math.Sign because System.Math source code simply isn't released/available?

Comment: Are you using VS 2008 Service Pack 1?

Comment: Yes, version is 9.0.30729.1 SP.

Comment: Same exact problem: with VS2008 SP1 (9.0.307279.1), Vista SP2, I've downloaded the latest source code component (Dotnetfx_4016_VistaSP2) and followed every instruction to a tee. Still, like Sam, I can step into everything (e.g. System.Web, 2.0.50727.4016) but can’t step into mscorlib (2.0.50727.4200) – for reference, the symbols for mscorlib are repeatedly downloaded from /download/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/4D0B2695F5144B4D8F24004284FE26191/mscorlib.pd_.

Answer (score 8):

You need to load the symbols for `mscorlib.dll` first.

Click Debug, Windows, Modules, then right-click on `mscorlib.dll` and click Load Symbols.

Then, try again.  FYI, the simplest way to make sure that .Net source debugging is working is to try to view the source of a method in your call stack.

Comment: I tried this.  "Symbol status" says "Symbols loaded."  The .pdb file is 763KB; is this the right size?

Comment: No, it isn't.  For .Net 3.5 SP0, my mscorlib.pdb is 8,252 KB.  Try deleting the .pdb file from the symbol cache and and trying again.

Comment: How do you delete and re-add?  mscorlib.pdb does not seem to exist on my machine.  I have followed these directions, but it has not helped:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.71).aspx  (I am trying to step through a VS2003 project that I am porting.

Comment: VS2012 and no luck with the above or any of the directions online.  Symbols are loaded for mscorlib.dll, but still doesn't work.  I've never had much luck with .NET framework source stepping.  Really makes debugging difficult especially with frameworks like MVC where exceptions originate in pipelines outside of any of your code, and exceptions don't contain contextual information like parameter values.  Oh great, you failed to cast some property during model binding but I have no idea which one.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't step into some code because I didn't realise I was using a mock. :)